# how to check if user's uploaded files are secure

Tags: python, apache, flask

I am new to flask. My apology if this question has been discussed before. I am wondering if my app allows users to upload their files, how can I ensure their uploaded files are secure, no virus or no threats to the server? Should I use any specific anti-virus softwares to scan their files? Or is there any file permission for specific folders or files I should set up. Let's say if I am using Apache as server on Linux for example. I've been looking for solution to this for a bit, but still did not find clear answers. Really appreciate if there is any suggestion.

Comment: This is really easy. If you receive a file, how do you check if the file is secure ? Actually, there is no good answer to your questions.

Comment: There are reasons why large internet companies such as Google or Facebook have dedicated security teams. These things are not solved problems, and threats to a server can come in an incredibly large number of forms. The only thing you can do is to take security into consideration when developing your application as much as possible, and following modern security guidelines. Everything you allow a user to do with your web application also incorporates a security risk. How big this risk is depends on your application, and makes it very difficult to answer in general.

Answer (score 2):

You can do what the SMTP servers (email) administrators do, install Clamd or a similar antivirus, and use it to analyze the received files.

Here you can find a tutorial for installing it on CentOS https://www.centosblog.com/how-to-install-clamav-and-configure-daily-scanning-on-centos/

As you tagged your question with `python` here's an extension that you can use to interact with clamd from python, it is properly called `pyClamd` http://xael.org/pages/pyclamd-en.html

Also, being a Linux machine, if nothing uploaded ever gets the `+x` permission it won't be executed, so you're protecting users that download the files, not the machine itself, because the machine is protected by being a Linux system.